# react native cancel setTimeout

Tags: javascript, react-native, settimeout

I want to implement an 'is typing' message in my react native app. I'm using websockets for sending messages.

I have implemented a useEffect function which is called whenever the message state changes (this state contains the message the user is currently typing). Whenever `message.length % 2 === 0`, and 'is typing' socket message should be send. After 2 seconds, a new message 'stop is typing' should be send.

```
let timeout;

// useCallback function depending on message and timeout
// this function checks the length of the message and sends
// a start typing socket message
// after 2 seconds, an end typing socket message should be send
// OR this should be cancelled if the user is still typing
const isTypingFunction = useCallback(() => {
  if (message.length > 0 && message.length % 2 === 0) {
    if (timeout) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    socket.send(__start_message_here__);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      socket.send(__end_message_here__);
    }, 2000);
  }
}, [message, timeout]);

// useEffect function to run the isTypingFunction
useEffect(() => {
  isTypingFunction();
}, [message]);
```

The problem is: the previous setTimeout's are **not** cancelled. When I start typing, in the other console I see the start typing messages coming, but after a while, the end typing messages are also coming. I only want 1 end typing message (the last one) to actually be send.

Answer (score 0):

You're not persisting your `timeout` variable through renders, therefore you can't cancel the previous timeouts. You can use `useRef` to persist any value through renders. Try this code:

```
const timeoutHandle = useRef(0);

// useCallback function depending on message and timeout
// this function checks the length of the message and sends
// a start typing socket message
// after 2 seconds, an end typing socket message should be send
// OR this should be cancelled if the user is still typing
const isTypingFunction = useCallback(() => {
  if (message.length > 0 && message.length % 2 === 0) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle.current);
    socket.send(__start_message_here__);
    timeoutHandle.current = setTimeout(() => {
      socket.send(__end_message_here__);
    }, 2000);
  }
}, [message]);

// useEffect function to run the isTypingFunction
useEffect(() => {
  isTypingFunction();
}, [message]);
```